How to list all blocked IPs and the related nft rule?
Recent versions of Linux's have switched for iptables to nftables. However, I am newbie with the nft command. So, my question is: How do I list all specific IPs (IPv4 & IPv6) that are blocked "somehow" by nftables and display also the related rule?
A command like this:
# nft list ruleset | grep elements
# Warning: table ip filter is managed by iptables-nft, do not touch!
# Warning: table ip nat is managed by iptables-nft, do not touch!
# Warning: table ip6 filter is managed by iptables-nft, do not touch!
# Warning: table ip6 nat is managed by iptables-nft, do not touch!
# Warning: XT target MASQUERADE not found
# Warning: XT target MASQUERADE not found
        elements = { 46.154.40.110 }

partially gets the output I need. (See last line of output). But, it is not convenient when there are many IPs and it does not display the rule table inet f2b-table and set addr-set-sshd that I need in this case.
Is there a more elegant solution (possibly using the --json option)?
Note: What I am looking for are individual addresses that are blocked by fail2ban or sshguard. So, I am not in such a complicated case here.

In addition to IP-addresses that are referenced explicitly, your rules may also use CIDR/netmask notations to reference complete  IP-address ranges. Determination  if the specific IP-address you're investigating falls into one more of such  subnets  is likely an additional complication that you won't easily solve with a simple grep

I am not investigating for a specific address; I just want to get a complete list of all blocked IPs or subnets and the reason.

Your logic for finding IP-addresses that "are blocked somehow"  also falls short when you have rules that are not blocklists (with lists of IP-addresses/networks that are rejected)  but allowlists that reject all except a specific short list of allowed addresses/networks. - Which makes investigating firewall issues for anything but the most trivial firewall configurations a PITA and investigating the complete rule set often a requirement
